# spring MVC : form : radiobutton for Boolean property

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring

I just want to know how to use a Boolean in a Spring mvc form.

I try with this code:

My jsp:

```
<form:radiobutton path="dateInterval" value="false" cssClass="radio"/>
<form:radiobutton path="dateInterval" value="true" cssClass="radio"/>
```

The property on the pojo:

```
private Boolean dateInterval = false;
```

But my dateInterval property is always null!

Comment: there are getter and setter for the property dateInterval.

Comment: A common mistake is to use isBlah for the property Boolean blah;  This is wrong.  isBlah will only work for type boolean.  Use getBlah for Boolean blah;

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have them working on my form like this:

```
<form:radiobutton path="someProperty" value="true"/>
    <spring:message code="label.roundYes"/>
<form:radiobutton path="someProperty" value="false"/>
    <spring:message code="label.roundNo"/>
```

and in my model object the someProperty looks like this:

```
private boolean someProperty = false;
```

That works fine.  I haven't tried it with 'Boolean'.  Maybe just try it with boolean and see if it helps.

Comment: yes, you right, it works! Sorry for this stupid question! Works perfectly with a boolean and not Boolean. Thank you.

Comment: Boolean is useful when you don't want true or false to be selected initially.  This answer doesn't asnwer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify things: In my opinion it also works with **Boolean** Object. I have a form using Spring 3 and this setup is running perfect (using true/false/null Values as an Option):

Form JSP:

```
<form:radiobutton path="tour.routeNachZeit" value="true" />
<form:radiobutton path="tour.routeNachZeit" value="false" />
```

Model Object (named **Tour**):

```
private Boolean routeNachZeit;
```

Therefore I don't unterstand why I should have changed my Property to *simple boolean*. This works in my case.

My help came from this [post in the Spring Forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/27448-binding-null-to-a-java-boolean-from-a-form-select?p=282770#post282770).