# How can I handle a tri-state Boolean with Spring MVC 3 Form radiobutton tags?

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc, binding

I have a tri-state `Boolean` attribute (true, false, and null) in of one of my objects, and I don't know how to properly bind it using the Spring Forms tags. I would like to use a series of 3 radio buttons (true, false, and null), but it seems that Spring does not like what I'm trying thus far.

Here's the backing POJO:

```
public class Spirit {
    /*** Private Fields **/
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Boolean isAlive;

    /*** Constructor **/
    public Spirit() {}

    /*** Getters **/
    public Integer getId() {return id;}
    public String getName() {return name;}
    public Boolean isAlive() {return isAlive;}

    /*** Setters **/
    public void setId(Integer id) {this.id = id;}
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public void isAlive(Boolean isAlive) {this.isAlive = isAlive;}
}
```

And here's the form I'm using (that doesn't work):

```
<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="spirit">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="spirit_name">Name</label></th>
            <td><sf:input path="name" id="spirit_name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="spirit_isAlive">Livelyness</label></th>
            <td>N/A: <sf:radiobutton path="isalive" value="null" /> Alive: <sf:radiobutton path="isalive" value="true" /> Dead: <sf:radiobutton path="isalive" value="false" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <sf:hidden path="id"/>
    <input type="submit" value="save" />                
</sf:form>
```

The error I'm getting:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'isAlive' of bean class [com.example.Spirit]: Bean property 'isAlive' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:699)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:98)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:224)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractCheckedElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractCheckedElementTag.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.writeTagContent(AbstractSingleCheckedElementTag.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.spirits.edit_jsp._jspx_meth_sf_005fradiobutton_005f0(edit_jsp.java:523)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.spirits.edit_jsp._jspService(edit_jsp.java:201)
```

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461107/spring-mvc-form-radiobutton-for-boolean-property) that is very similar, but the solution in that case was to simply change the type to `boolean`, rather than `Boolean`. Unfortunately, changing the get/set methods for the tri-state is only available as a last-resort option. What is it that I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't specify `value=null` in the JSP Tag. This will result in the browser sending a value of `isalive=null` in the HTTP POST.

Since there is no way to bind `"null"` (the String) to a `Boolean`, this rightfully throws an error.

If the radio button is not selected by the user, then the browser will not send anything for the form parameter (or it will send `isalive=`, I forget which - but it does not matter). In this case Spring will not attempt to bind the field, which will leave your POJO with a `isAlive` field with `null` value.

So in summary - if you set `value=null` in the HTML/JSP tag, you are telling the browser to POST a *string* literal `null`. Just leave it out.

Comment: Having the user not select a radio button is great, but (without using javascript) how can the radio buttons be un-selected then? As far as I know, there is no way to do this with the native browser UI, which is why I have 3 radio buttons in the 1st place.

Comment: It won't send `isalive` at all.

Comment: Why do you need to unselect? (And if you do, just set the Boolean model attribute back to null).

Comment: Wouldn't you just set `value=""` in this case for the "unselect" choice? Note that according to [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#radio), one of the radio buttons always needs to be selected. A dropdown might be a better choice for an input element where you want the user to choose either "true", "false", or "unselected".

Comment: @dbreaux - I need to model a true tri-state, so any of the 5 different state transitions are valid, hence the need to "unselect".

Comment: @matt - `value=""` throws an `unable to find method with [0] parameters` error. I think you are right though that a dropdown may be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, what I ended up doing was to use a `<select>` box for the values that the JSP was sending and binding, and then manipulated the UI via javascript to hide the actual select box and update it based on the user interacting with custom controls.

This worked quite well, since I eventually needed to have more than 3 states, but the downside is that it requires an extra class to model the states.